# Is it better to generate html for an ajax function in the JS handler or in the PHP ajax function?

Tags: php, ajax, design-patterns, jquery

I'm designing some UI's for a product and we want to utilize jQuery and PHP. The content to generate is a list of checkboxes (10-100) that a user will be modifying (removing multiple at a time and changing the entries). I thought I'd try something new and ask StackOverflow (read: you) what is preferred: generate the html in the php call and return, or return JSON data that jQuery can than go and generate the html checkboxes using.

I appreciate the feedback! My preferred method so far is to let PHP generate html because it knows more about the data at the time of modification (it's interacting with the database and it could build the html easy enough without having to pass back id's, names, etc in JSON).

Thanks!

[Edit] Bandwidth is not a constraint. This is an internal intranet application. The information needing to be printed to the user will not require dom modification after the fact (outside of checkboxes, but that's built in to the browser...) some good points have been made on the amount of data that's being passed back though:

passing back

Label

vs.
{
"Label": "Unique_ID"
}

is obviously a lot of redundancy.

Comment: Where is the majority of your non-Ajax HTML developed? I might give different answers depending on if it's (a) written along with the PHP, in intermingled server-side code, or (b) well-separated from the PHP using a templating system, and written by a front-end developer who's also doing the jQuery. Sometimes the human factor can swing it, when there's an otherwise fairly arbitrary choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really no right/wrong way to do this.  Passing JSON back, and then using client-site processing to turn that into HTML uses less bandwidth, but more local processing power.  Passing HTML back, uses more bandwidth and less local processing (these are seriously minor points, only if you're talking extremely popular or frequently changing sites might it even be relevant).

**Return Flexibility - HTML**

One of the benefits to HTML passing is you can return **anything** if the request causes an error, or could generate different types of data you just return different HTML.  If you're returning JSON, the parsing script has to deal with these alternate structures (ie error handling, and/or multiple structure parsing algorithms).

**Local Processing - JSON**

If you're localizing, sorting, or framing the data from the user's point of view, it may well be simpler to return JSON and then use client side scripts to interpret.  For example when user=2, reporting "You" instead of "Mike" might be a nice personalization touch.  You could do this server side, but now the script needs to take that into account, so the same query needs to return different data based on context (again not impossible).  You can keep your server code more generic by using client side scripts to perform this.

**Local Presenting - JSON**

Perhaps a single command collects the data, but there's multiple parts of the page that should be updated with what's returned.  With an HTML approach, you either need separate queries, or some sort of delimiter in your return (with escapes!), and a local processing script to decide what goes where... with a JSON approach, the local processing script can update the locations from the same single source as it's retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

You could approach the question both from the aspect of server burden and in terms of client performance.

If your server is having to dynamically generate the HTML output for every user, it will endure a somewhat higher burden than if you delegated the content-generation to client-side JavaScript. Clients have abundant computing power at their disposal, so feel free to have them collectively shoulder the burden rather than having your server do all the work (which could easily add up, depending on how busy your server is).

Likewise, generating the HTML markup on the server results in a significantly larger page download for the client. The markup for a hundred check-boxes could easily add kilobytes to the size of the page, while the data itself--which is all you would send using the JSON approach--is much smaller. Of course, larger page downloads mean longer download times for the client. We as web developers often forget that there are still quite a few people who still have dial-up internet connections.

For these reasons, I would personally opt for sending the data via JSON and doing DOM-modification via JavaScript.

Cheers,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends.  If you are going to be doing DOM manipulation on the new data, then you pretty much have to append the elements using jQuery.  If there is no such manipulation needed, then you can just print it out with php and add the blob.

I think that the latter is much easier and simpler, so if you don't need to do DOM manipulation on the elements, you can just add the html blob from php.